# API Request to Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, api

I'm using a Crypto API that gives me the Time, Open, High, Low, Close Values of the last weeks back. I just need the first row.

The input:

```
[[1635260400000, 53744.5, 53744.5, 53430.71, 53430.71], [1635262200000, 53635.49, 53899.73, 53635.49, 53899.73], [1635264000000, 53850.63, 54258.62, 53779.11, 54242.25], [1635265800000, 54264.32, 54264.32, 53909.02, 54003.42]]
```

I've tried:

```
resp = pd.read_csv('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/ohlc?vs_currency=eur&days=1')
resp = resp.astype(str)


Time = resp[resp.columns[0]]
Open = resp[resp.columns[1]]
High = resp[resp.columns[2]]
Low = resp[resp.columns[3]]
Close = resp[resp.columns[4]]
```

But this doesn't work as I can't process it(i wanted to process it from object to str to double or float). I want to have each value as a double in a different variable. Im kinda stuck at this.

Comment: Do you really need Pandas? Or separate variables when you should have a dataframe with rows?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think i know what you mean but i don't quit know how to do it

Comment: Have you tried using requests? `resp = requests.get(url).json()`? This will already be integers/floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using pandas is that the JSON array creates one row with several columns.

If you expect to just loop over the JSON array, I suggest using requests rather than pandas.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/ohlc?vs_currency=eur&days=1')

for row in resp.json():
   timestamp, open_price, high, low, close = row
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use read_json:

```
resp = pd.read_json('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/ohlc?vs_currency=eur&days=1')
resp = resp.astype(float)

Time = resp[resp.columns[0]]
Open = resp[resp.columns[1]]
High = resp[resp.columns[2]]
Low = resp[resp.columns[3]]
Close = resp[resp.columns[4]]
```

But the previous solution is more compact and understandable.